# Relationship between pdfs of two related random vectors

Tags: probability, random-variables, self-learning

In a solution to a probability exercise, there was the following claim I couldn't understand:

Consider a random vector (signal) $y=x+w$ where $w$ is a noise random vector (signal) with energy $\lVert w\rVert_2<\epsilon$, where $\epsilon >0$ and we assume having the true probability density function (pdf) $f_x(x)$ of the random vector $x$, then $f_x(x)\ge f_x(y)$.

Can anyone help? I looked into functions of two random variables but didn't help since here we are comparing two $f_x(\cdot)$ and not $f_y(y)$ against $f_x(x)$ and $f_w(w)$.

Comment: The expression $f_X(x)\ge f_X(y)$ is confusing.  It looks like you are comparing the value of a function at a point x against a value of the same function at a point y.  ????

Comment: @herbsteinberg I have put the edited the question to the exact formatting of the exercise. My under standing is that we compare the pdf under $X$ of random vector $x$ with the pdf under $X$ of random vector $y$. The notation confuses me too and any pointers or correction about that and about the claim would be appreciated.

Comment: Notation should have$f_X(x) \ and f_Y(x)$ as density functions.  Furthermore a density function can't dominate another density function,(other than identical) since their integrals are both  = 1.

Comment: @herbsteinberg does this mean that something's wrong with the claim?

Comment: @herbsteinberg what if we replace $f_X(x)$ and $f_X(y)$ by probabilities $P_X(x)$ and $P_X(y)$, does the claim $P_X(x) \ge P_X(y)$ make more sense this way? Is there a way to interpret the claim so it makes sense?

Comment: You need to give precise definitions for $P_X(x)\ and\ P_X(y)$.  What are they the probabilities of?

Comment: @herbsteinberg I unfortunately don't know! I'm just trying to find a way to decode the claim of the exercise along with its notation so that it makes sense.

Comment: @herbsteinberg does it help if we interpret $f_X(x)$ as the pdf of random vector $X$ evaluated at vector-point $x$ and $f_X(y)$ as the pdf of random vector $X$ evaluated at vector-point $y$? Does $f_X(x)\ge f_X(y)$ make sense this way? taking into account the given information (i.e. knowing pdf of $X$ and that noise  is such that $||w||_2\le \epsilon$.

Comment: You need to clarify which are random vectors and which are points in space.  Originally you have y=x+w, where y,x,w are random.  Then you introduce X - how does it relate?  You seem to be confused as to the definition of a probability.  For example $P_X(x)$ means the probability that $X\le x$, where X is a real valued random variable and x is a real number.  Also you have to extra careful when dealing with vectors.

Comment: @herbsteinberg You're totally right. There should be no $X$ in here. I forgot to change it to $x$ when I edited the problem formulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a signal of amplitude X, what is the effect on the distribution of the amplitude when noise of amplitude W is added?  Let Y=X+W be the observed signal amplitude.  Define $f_X(x)$ as the probability density of X and $f_Y(x)$ as the probability density of Y.  Let $f_X(u)$ have its maximum at v, then $f_X(v)\gt f_Y(v)$.  The point is that the noise spreads the distribution of the received signal so that it is not as sharp as the signal without noise.

Comment: In the third line, you meant to write $f_X(x)$ not $f_X(u)$, right?

Comment: Why does the noise spread the distribution of the received signal?

Comment: I think I got it. Since we usually consider signal and noise independent, then the received signal's variance is the sum of the signal and noise variances. This implies more spread for the received signal, and since pdfs must sum up to 1, the maximum of pdf of $y$ would be smaller than max of pdf of $x$.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable exercise question, so maybe the question wasn't formulated correctly. Thanks for your patience and effort. Don't have enough points to upvote but I'll choose it as the right answer.